# Hibernate, SQL Server 2016 = SQL Error: 207 - Invalid column name

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

my problem is that I have 2 schemas in SQL Server 2016, but with the same tables. I've altered both, and added 3 same columns each. But when hibernate wants to add new data to this altered tables it gives me an exception

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name 'claim_number'.
```

And yes, name of columns matches the names added in @Column.

```
@Column(name = "claim_number", nullable = true, length = 30)
private String claimNumber;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please display how you have been add new data?

Comment: You could just add "@id" before "@Column"

Comment: I'm inserting data using Spring Data JPA repositories, and yup this entity has an @Id.

Answer (score 3):

## Problem#1:

**Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name 'claim_number'.**

**Issue Analysis:**

If we check the column name, we will find that,

i) it contains **underscore("_").**

**Solution#1:**

Hibernate uses various type of naming strategy. It the column contains underscore, then we need to use the following naming strategy.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

*N.B: For checking the error, you can add the following properties in **application.properties** file. It will show sql in console and you can make decision. So please add it:*

```
# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true.
```

## Problem#2:

**Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name 'claimnumber'.**

**Issue Analysis:**

If we check the column name, we will find that,

i) it contains **lowercase string**. No underscore.

**Solution#2:**

Sometimes developers create a table with columns which contains only lowercase string. On that time we need to use another naming strategy of hibernate.

```
# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

Comment: sorry, it was almost 2 years ago, and I can't remember how I solved this issue, so I can't mark your answer.

Comment: @egzaell Actually I got same error and fixed this issue. I have made some R&D and got this two approaches to resolve the issue. So I am here to share my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was a similar one but with Spring Boot + Hibernate + SQL Server.
Check the solution and see if you can apply something similar.

[Hibernate @Column annotation not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733010/hibernate-column-annotation-not-work)

Comment: Thanks but it's something new, I'm working in a big app, and problem is with just these new columns.